# Very weird behavior when running external command in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Why does

```
Import["!python --version", "Text"]
```

work on the commandline but not in the frontend of Mathematica 8 (running on a Mac)?

Shell:

```
"Python 2.7.1 -- EPD 7.0-2 (64-bit)"
```

Frontend:

```
""
```

Update:

Ok, the path is not (really) the problem, as

```
Import["!which python", "Text"]
```

yields

```
"/usr/bin/python"
```

in the frontend and

```
"/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python"
```

in the shell (which is a different python version I have installed on my system). Nevertheless, neither

```
Import["!/usr/bin/python --version", "Text"]
```

nor

```
Import[
"!/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python --version",
"Text"]
```

yield the correct output in the frontend. But the usage of different shells in the frontend and the terminal version could be a hint to why Mathematica is misbehaving.

Comment: Try with the full path instead.

Comment: I don't think it's a different shell. `Import["!echo $SHELL","Text"]` reports the correct shell for me.

Comment: Ok, I don't know the cause. It's not the system path, however.

Comment: I get the same behaviour (in Ubuntu 10.10) and I only have one version of Python installed: `Import["!which python", "Text"]` yields `Python 2.6.6` in both the Notebook and Mma shell. But `Import["!/usr/bin/python --version", "Text"]` yields `Python 2.6.6` in the shell and nothing in the frontend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`python --version` writes its response to the standard error stream, but `Import` only captures the standard output stream.  To see the response, redirect *stderr* to *stdout*.  In most shells (even Windows), this can be achieved using the magic incantation `2>&1`:

```
Import["!python --version 2>&1", "Text"]
```

**Front-end Different From Command-line?**

The `Import` command *appears* to function differently when run in the command-line version of Mathematica, but appearances can be deceiving.  Here is a transcript:

```
$ math
Mathematica 8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2011 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= Import["!python --version","Text"]
Python 2.6.4

Out[1]=
```

Note that `Out[1]` is blank.  The version string appears in the transcript, but this is due to the fact that the standard error stream is being displayed in the terminal window, interspersed with the standard output from Mathematica.  This is even more clear if we assign the result to a variable and (attempt to) suppress the output using `;`:

```
In[2]:= v=Import["!python --version","Text"];
Python 2.6.4

In[3]:= v

Out[3]=
```

There shouldn't have been any output, but we still see the standard error stream displayed in the terminal window.  `v` is blank, showing that the value of the `Import` expression was blank as well.

Comment: good find! That's weird though, because on my machine `vi --version 1>stdout 2>stderr` and several others print only to stdout whereas it's the other way round for python. +1

Comment: @WReach: So why does the naive `Import` command work in the Mathematica shell?

Comment: @Simon Oh, I see what you mean... it only appears to work when you run the `math` command.  You are just seeing the `stderr` output interspersed with the `math` output.  The return value is blank, just like in the front-end.

Comment: Nice catch! But why (as Simon already asked) is the terminal version of Import["!python --version", "Text"] catching the error stream? Nevertheless, thank you WReach!

Comment: @phantomas1234 I am not seeing that behaviour.  If I execute `p=Import["!python --version", "Text"];p`, `p` is assigned an empty string.  I do *see* the contents of the `stderr` displayed in the terminal window, but it is neither returned to Mathematica nor stored into `p`.  Is that what happens for you?

Comment: @WReach: Well spotted - that's exactly what's happening and I was too stupid to notice it. +1

Comment: @WReach Big thanks for uncovering the `2>&1` magic! Where is it documented (at least for Windows)?

Comment: @Alexy: On unix systems, `>` is the [redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) command, `2` denotes standard error and `1` denotes standard output. So `2>&1` redirects standard error to the standard output. The syntax is similar on non-POSIX shells like [Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). You can also redirect it to different files like I did in the first comment on this answer. However, it is not clear why python sends it to standard error, when nearly every other program on my machine sends it to standard output.

Comment: I have never seen `2>&1` before. +1  What is the role of `&`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "`>&`" under Windows is a handle redirection operator as explained [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) (thanks [yoda](http://stackoverflow.com/users/616736/yoda) for the link!).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: `a>&b` redirects from handle `a` to `b`, and outputs it to where ever `b` is written to. Just `>` by itself writes to a file. So if you did `2>1`, it would write the standard error to a file named `1`. By default, standard output is printed to the screen, so `2>&1` also prints the error to the screen. On the other hand if you had written `1>file 2>&1`, now you are redirecting std output to `file` and the second command redirects the std error also to `file`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: BTW, congrats on the silver mma badge. Both Leonid and you earned it on the same day (my day, not UTC).

Comment: @WReach: Have a 10th vote, and another "Nice answer" badge =)

Answer (score 3):

[WReach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170960/very-weird-behavior-when-running-external-command-in-mathematica/6171556#6171556) has the answer to your problem. However, my point still remains that the instance of the shell invoked by mathematica does not have the path variable set correctly. Here's some info from mine:

[image]

The shell is correct, but the path is the default path. So source my modified path and then invoke `python --version`:

[image]

Comment: It wasn't me, but probably because it did not appear to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but WReach's answer has been acknowledged. Like shown in my answer it still wouldn't have given the OP the version info he was looking for, because the mma shell instance has the wrong paths and OP needs to set it manually. Anyway, no harm done.

Comment: I just gave you a +1.  Feel better now? :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks :) I was merely curious to know their reasoning. Usually when I get a downvote, I know I deserved it ;)